# Key ordering in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I've stumbled upon something which confuses me. Before I though that if you save an array and it's keys in integers, the array will automaticly sort itself.
That is, if I add the key `2`, before the key `1`, I'd though that the array would be sorted by the lowest number:

```
Array
(
    [1] => one
    [2] => two
)
```

Instead it comes up like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => two
    [1] => one
)
```

Operation:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[2] = 'two';
$arr[1] = 'one';
```

This might seem like nothing, but sometimes I use `foreach()` or store ids in arrays and count on them to be sortered for maybe a `INSERT`-query, and then they need to be in correct order (due to AUTO INCREMENT).

So *the question*:
What is the expected ordering result in php?

I have a rather strong memory that I've sorted out arrays previously through output #1. Does this differ from php-version to php-version?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: how did you end up with that array? i.e. what array operation did you use?

Comment: AFAIK items in an array are in the order in which you add them to the array. You can use some built-in PHP functions to sort the array by key.

Comment: `$arr[2] = 'blabla'` will just push element to the end of the array hence why, use `ksort` to re order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A PHP array is actually an ordered map. It keeps the order, earlier elements will precede later ones.

You can use [ksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to sort the array by key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess my memory failed me that this was sorted automaticly on previous projects.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://technosophos.com/content/php-arrays-are-not-arrays) explains that PHP arrays are in fact ordered hash maps where the keys are stored in the order they were generated.

If you want a more traditional array behavior try the [SPLFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) class.